# Нужно ли обособлять "наверняка"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

В предложении "Наверняка, это случилось в прошлом году" нужно ли обособлять наверняка?

Answer (score 4):

(Курс подготовки к ЕГЭ. Урок 30, Российская газета 14.04.2011)

> Не являются вводными и ***не*** выделяются запятыми следующие слова и
>   сочетания:
>
> *г) **наверняка**, в конечном счете, в конце концов*

https://rg.ru/2011/04/13/zanatie31-site.html

Книжный пример:

> *Наверняка вы помните, что к вам заходила молодая красивая женщина,*
>   *доктор Стелла Конвей.* (А. Леонтьев, "Лес разбуженных снов", 2017)

**P.S.** Можно представить себе вариант с запятой только в случае, когда слово "наверняка" является кратким ответом на вопрос в диалоге:

- Но он понял-таки, что придётся на ней жениться?
- Наверняка, это случилось в прошлом году.

Процитирую подробно источник от безусловно авторитетного автора (**Розенталь Д.Э.** "Русский язык" (для школьников и поступающих в вузы). М., "Дрофа", 2001. §72, упр. 391-394):

> Слова, которые **никогда** не бывают вводными (наречия, союзы, частицы и сочетания слов): *авось, большей частью, буквально, будто, будто бы,
>   вдобавок, в довершение всего, вдруг, ведь, весьма, в конечном счете,
>   вот, вообще (в значении "в целом", "обычно"), вряд ли, всё же, всё
>   равно, всё-таки, даже, едва ли, единственно, именно, иногда,
>   исключительно, как будто, как бы, как-никак, как раз, к тому же, лишь,
>   между тем, **наверняка**, на редкость, небось, неужели, непременно,
>   определенно, особенно, поистине, пока, положительно, по-прежнему,
>   почти, поэтому, приблизительно, примерно, притом, причем, при этом,
>   просто, пускай, пусть, разве решительно, словно, только якобы.*

Comment: В ряде словарей русского языка слово «наверняка» рассматривается как вводное в значении «конечно, разумеется». Но это редко. Например: Он, наверняка, опоздает.

Comment: Сложившаяся норма пунктуации важнее "ряда словарей" и квазинаучных публикаций. Есть даже статья, в которой для иллюстрации берётся книжный пример без запятых (иного примера не нашлось и у "учёного"), в который автор статьи (для подтверждения своей веры в вводность "модалятов") их незаметно вставляет. https://www.expeducation.ru/ru/article/view?id=10500

Comment: Так по ссылке же даже пример есть с вводным значением: `Его, наверняка, снимали в эпоху немого кино (А. Геласимов. Нежный возраст)`. И расшифровывается дальше, что здесь это отнаречный модалят в функции обособленного вводного слова. То есть всё-таки бывает, хоть и редко.

Comment: Я про этот пример и говорю: в книге запятых нет, как и во всех других книгах.

Comment: То есть делаем вывод, что в данном вопросе много противоречий: словари, правила на сайтах, научные работы, литература. И автор имеет право решать сам, основываясь на задумке.

Comment: От автора это едва ли зависит: пока ни один автор не убедил в допустимости "авторской" пунктуации вокруг этого слова _корректора_ издательства.

Comment: Но тем не менее в выводе статьи не сказано, что использовать запятые ошибка. А повторять за большинством - это тенденция любого общества.

Comment: Не обязательно же все возможные ошибки перечислять сразу после изложения правил :). Но есть и такие учебные материалы: карточка 10 с заголовком "**Есть ли слова, которые ошибочно выделяют запятыми?**"  приводит там наше многострадальное слово. https://meduza.io/cards/kak-pravilno-stavit-znaki-prepinaniya

Comment: Да не перечислять ошибки, а сказать: можно или нельзя выделять.

Comment: Серьёзно? Нет запятых в оригинале? Предугадали, что не буду перечитывать всю статью? Хитрец. А вот вам ход конём - фрагмент из этого рассказа: https://i.imgur.com/czdGuPM.png Могу и ссылку на весь рассказ дать.

Comment: Судя по рваным отступам в абзацах, это компьютерный набор. Вот скан страницы: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=KFS8uU-G9lIC&hl=ru&pg=PT106&img=1&zoom=3&ots=_QS_6UhESw&sig=ACfU3U3YTlyM4MmOxO3D-CyEgrIs3sD17A&w=1280

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://magazines.gorky.media/october/2001/12/nezhnyj-vozrast.html Будут они там запятые менять... Да никто и близко не станет менять изданный текст. Читать нужно было внимательно работу, прежде чем утверждать, что автор добавляет запятые. И это полный бред, так как смысл исследования - изучение значения оригинального текста. А чтобы менять запятые, можно с таким же успехом и свои предложения придумать. Ладно, проехали.

Comment: Я так и подумал, что скриншот. Оптическое распознавание текста (раз уж это коллекция изданного другими) всегда требует коррекции на предмет технических ошибок. Так что техкорректор веб-ресурса (у которого ответственность поменьше издательской) мог по своему разумению и грамоту за одно "поправить" - потеряла глупая машина запятые.

Comment: Сетевое издание «Горький» зарегистрировано в Роскомнадзоре. Они станут пиратить статьи без лицензии, перепечатывая? У них исходники имеются, предоставленные самим автором рассказа. Какое ещё распознавание? Если бы автор научной статьи менял бы запятые, то он исследовал бы оба варианта (с запятыми и без), чего не наблюдается. Очевидно же, что вы умышленно вводите в заблуждение. Иначе бы давно была бы цитата автора статьи, что он будет менять запятые и при этом не исследовать (по-вашему) оригинал. Полный маразм. Мне лень pdf искать. В последней ред. Розенталя такого правила нет.

Comment: @oleedd обойдемся без «не несите бред», давайте использовать менее эмоциональную лексику.

Answer (score 2):

***Наверняка, //это случилось // в прошлом году.***

Вопрос оказался интересным (судя по количеству комментариев), поэтому я решила высказать **свое мнение**.

**Пояснение**

1) **Читаем словарь**

**НАВЕРНЯКА. I. нареч. Разг**. 1. Несомненно, верно, точно. Нельзя н. сказать, что опыт удался. Никто не знал н. дату рождения художника. Приду н. 2. С верным расчётом, безошибочно. Действовать н. Всё рассчитать н. **II. вводн. сл. Конечно, несомненно, разумеется.** Он, н., опять опоздает. Работу, н., опять придётся переделывать. Этого количества, н., будет мало.

2) Наречие обозначает абсолютную уверенность говорящего, также у наречия **более строгая позиция,** так как между глаголом и наречием существует присловная грамматическая связь (примыкание).

3) Вводное слово тоже обозначает уверенность говорящего, но это **не точное знание, а предположение.**   Позиция в предложении у вводного слова более свободная, оно **не образует грамматической связи** с членами предложения (при этом  в начале предложения оно встречается довольно часто).

3) **Интонационный анализ**

***НавернякА, //это случилось //в прОшлом году.***

Вводное слово интонационно  входит в первую часть предложения, но именно на него падает ударение (логическим ударением выделена пара слов  *навернякА — в прОшлом году*).

Сравнить (для необособленного наречия): ***Наверняка это случИлось //в прошлом годУ.***

Здесь по смыслу **утверждается сам факт случившегося.**

3) Вывод

И по позиции слова в начале предложения, и по семантике, и по интонации **это вводное слово.**

4) **О практических примерах**

Если слово расположено **в середине предложения**, то его функцию определить сложнее, приходится анализировать ситуацию с точки зрения **смысла**.

Необособленные варианты действительно встречаются **значительное чаще**, но это не причина считать их единственно верными (альтернативный вариант с обособлением вводного слова, возможно,  не рассматривался раньше для простоты).

Примеры

51 процент от общего числа страховых компаний имеют уставный капитал менее 5 млн рублей. Они-то ***наверняка*** не доживут до 2007 года.  2002.09.19]

Октябрина Михайловна опять спросила про фильм. Его, ***наверняка***, снимали в эпоху немого кино. Всё-таки придётся смотреть. Жалко её обманывать. [Андрей Геласимов. Нежный возраст (2001)]

Comment: А что за словарь вы смотрели?

Comment: Обычный словарь Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру.Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года.

Comment: @Aer НАВЕРНЯКА (БТС) http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Не могу себе представить паузы после "наверняка" в начале предложения, кроме случая, когда это слово отвечает на вопрос собеседника, с последующим присоединением пояснения. "Ударение" вполне возможно, но паузы оно не создаёт.

Comment: А что вам помогает представить паузу после "наверное" в начале предложения (обычно произносят "наверно")?  И вот что еще важно: не всегда  вводное слово выделяется интонационно паузой, но при этом обычно всегда влияет на расстановку логических ударений. Можно сравнить: (1) Он, наверняка, уже дОма. - Он навернЯка уже дома. Я думаю, что вводное слово "наверняка" - это просто стилистический и отчасти семантический вариант "наверное"

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ второй**

**Для чего мы учимся?** Причины вырисовываются две: (1) чтобы сдать ЕГЭ, (2) чтобы научиться грамотно писать и при этом понимать и чувствовать родной язык.

Если для вас важно первое, то адрес указан **(курс подготовки к ЕГЭ),  надо только со сроком годности продукта не ошибиться.** Если важно второе, то я попробую дать еще один ответ.

1) Слово ***наверняка*** может иметь **два значения**.

Во-первых, это **наречие со значением гарантированной успешности действия**: бить, стрелять, обыграть, понравиться – и всё наверняка. Во-вторых,  это **модальное значение,** определяющее **возможность самого действия**: цензура наверняка не пропустит, доктор наверняка посоветует. Именно во втором значении ***наверняка*** может быть **вводным словом или наречием**, выражая предположение или абсолютную уверенность.

2) **В современном толковом словаре приведены оба варианта, что нельзя сказать об учебных сайтах** (возможно, они  просто недостаточно продвинуты в части обновления материала).

3) А теперь кратко о самом предложении.

***НавернякА, / это случилось  //  в прОшлом году.***

Представим, что ***наверняка*** – это наречие.

***Наверняка это случИлось //в прошлом годУ.***

В этом случае здесь **утверждается сам факт происшествия** прошлого года (это случилось наверняка), если кто-то думает, что ничего не случилось.

Но если это предположение  о том,  **когда** это случилось (собеседники пытаются вспомнить, в каком же это было году),  то тогда это **вводное слово**.

4) А как же ЕГЭ, где **запрещено** считать ***наверняка*** вводным словом?

Что ж, **выбор за вами**:  или понимание грамматических и семантических оттенков  речи,  или формализм и равнодушие к  языку.

Comment: Абсолютно! Любой язык построен на законах логики, а без логики и анализа не будет ни понимания языка, ни профессионализма. Слепо следуют правилам только "зомби" (те, что без мозгов и ними питаются - а таких, увы, большинство).

Comment: Спасибо, смело сказано. Правила не следует нарушать, но надо понимать их природу, различая  глубинную (логическую) основу и внешние формальные признаки, которые всегда подразумевают исключения  и индивидуальный подход к решению. И про людей вы верно сказали. По мнению психологов, нужно набрать вроде бы  около 10 процентов инакомыслящих, тогда система  изменится. А пока одинокие "умники"  проигрывают на всех фронтах, как у Окуджавы:  Дураком быть выгодно, да очень не хочется,
умным – очень хочется, да кончится битьем...

Comment: @Sharon, просто объясню ситуацию. У книги, которую мы пишем, 2 автора. Я предлагаю использовать в данном предложении "наверняка", соавтор - " наверное".  И так вот у нпс завязался небольшой спор. Заменить "наверняка" на "наверное" нет проблем, тогда и постановка запятой будет очевидной. Но мне очень хотелось бы оставить вариант с "наверняка".

Comment: @Sharon, а про ситуацию с предложением, объясню. Парень смотрит на свои ботинки и видит, что  они порваны. Говорит сам себе в монологе, что, наверняка, это случилось в прошлом году в схватке с волком. Имею в виду, что использование "навярнека" необязательно, просто было интересно.

Comment: Я думаю, что запятая в вашем примере нужна даже по формальным правилам. В словаре Кузнецова указано, что "наверняка" может быть вводным словом. Здесь  выражается предположение, возможные синонимы  "наверное, скорее всего". Позиция для вводного слова подходящая. Единственное препятствие - это список Розенталя, да и то не новый. В современной редакции этого слова нет, да и в любом случае Розенталь говорит о возможных отклонениях от приведенного им списка.

Comment: И мне кажется, что `наверняка` в этом контексте звучит красивее и интереснее, чем `наверное`. @Sharon У меня в подсознании есть 2 значения слова `наверняка`: точно, без сомнений и как аналог "наверное", с сомнением. Почему тогда в словарях нет второго значения? Может, это разговорное значение, так как у этих слов общий корень и этимология переплетается? Или оно раньше использовалось в значении "наверное"...

Comment: Слово "наверняка" достаточное интересное.  Оно не новое, в 19 веке уже использовалось. Сначала преимущественно в значении действовать наверняка  (с верным расчетом), затем в значении  знать наверняка (точно). А это уже ОЦЕНОЧНОЕ значение, и в этом случае наречие часто имеет пару среди вводных слов. Эта парочка может иметь  близкую семантику,  но грамматика у них разная. Фактически вводное слово отрывается от глагола и пускается в "свободное плавание". Теперь оно уже может характеризовать не только действие, но и все предложение, возможности его расширяются. Возможно, так всё это было.

Comment: Странно, что в словарях нет значения как аналог "наверное" ("скорее всего"), но мы его узнаём и понимаем. Может, из-за того, что в этих словах отличается только концовка, люди просто начали путать их значения, и закрепилось это неофициальное альтернативное значение (неуверенности)...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно.

В данном случае это слово вводное (его можно изъять без потери смысла) и употребляется в значении `наверное` (и его использовать более правильно).

В следующем предложении не нужна запятая, потому что можно задать вопрос `как?`:

Он действовал наверняка.

Comment: Чем вы объясните, что в книгах (см. гугл-книги) это слово **никогда** (ни в какой позиции) не обособляется? Значение слова, на мой взгляд, серьёзно отличается от "наверное" - почти как "уверенность" от "неувереннности".

Comment: Оно может быть в значении `точно` без запятых (можно задать вопрос `как?`) или с оттенком сомнения как вводное с запятыми. То есть два лексических смысла. Второй вариант не очень корректный, и лучше использовать `наверное`. Тут правило: https://mel.fm/pravopisaniye/3045869-comma_extortion

Comment: Там нет такого _правила_, есть только упоминание об источнике, на который ссылаются с недоверием, через слово "якобы". Нет и примеров литературного следования такому правилу. Пример правила: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_427

Comment: Пример из литературы (лучше из классика) можете привести? Общие соображения не всегда "работают". Я уже сказал, "ни в какой позиции" - специально искал в начале предложения - в книгах и это без запятой.

Comment: То есть рассматриваем, вводное это слово здесь или нет. Очевидно, что да, учитывая, что стоит в начале предложения. В художественной литературе общие правила иногда нарушаются. К тому же, не коллекционирую примеры из литературы. Тут лучше логическая аргументация.

Comment: Аргументация "так надо писать" - при том, что так никто не пишет, неубедительна.

Comment: Тут не так важна позиция, как то, что хотел сказать автор. Если `как было сделано?`, то запятые не нужны. А если автор хочет использовать как вводное - то нужны запятые. Это довольно спорно. Но везде указывается, что в значении вводного нужны запятые.

Comment: "Так надо писать" - такое выражение называется констатация)

Comment: А если не согласны, что запятая здесь нужна, то докажите, что `наверняка` здесь наречие, а не вводное. Впрочем, в данном случае оно однозначно может быть вводным и это логично. Так что наличие запятой 100% не ошибочно.

Comment: Я не обязан ничего доказывать, поскольку не размещал ответа на вопрос. А вот ответы здесь принято иллюстрировать практическими примерами, к чему я вас и призываю. Пока что я вижу, что корректоры всех издательств игнорируют общее правило, под которое вы пытаетесь подвести конкретное слово. Видимо, на то есть основание, хотя и скрытое.

Comment: Вывод такой. Используем проверку на наречие. Если можно заметь на `точно` без запятой, то она не нужна. И если можно заменить на `именно это случилось в прошлом году`, то запятая не нужна и `наверняка` здесь наречие. Такой вариант тоже возможен, но он меньше подходит. Уже стало понятно?

Comment: Так и не поняла: нужна ли запятая или нет?

Comment: Почему же так сложно найти примеры с запятой? Отвечаю. Потому что употребление `наверняка` в роли вводного неестественно и плохо звучит (включая данный пример с этого вопроса, о чём сказано в ответе, что лучше заменить). И в книгах так писать не станут. Там же выверена стилистика, чтобы всё хорошо звучало.

Comment: @Nara Mamedova Чтобы однозначно сказать, нужно знать, что тут больше имеется ввиду? `Наверное, это случилось` или `именно это случилось`, или `ну так да, это случилось`. Если ответа нет, то лучше с запятой. Но теоретически оба варианта возможны, но запятая заметно меняет смысл. Её отсутствие делает акцент на слове `это`.

Comment: @oleedd Здесь в значении "наверное", " не точно"..

Comment: Тогда запятая обязательна. Но в словарях вроде бы и нет такого значения. Например: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/наверняка То есть такая формулировка не совсем корректна и она разговорная, так как люди поймут такой смысл. И лучше его заменить на `наверное`, чтобы ни у кого не возникала мысль, что запятая не нужна. К тому же, если какие-то слова взаимозаменяемы, то постановка запятых не меняется. То есть если тут `наверняка` или `наверно`, то раз `наверно` не может быть без запятой, то и `наверняка` в этом же смысле тоже не может быть без запятой, но в другом смысле может.